# Bound events lost in nested template (?)

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I'm facing a problem here and I'm not sure whether it's a bug or my stupidness.

I've build a widget, based on this template:

```
<!--  TEMPLATE A  -->
<div class="mplc-widget"> 
 <div class="mplc-widget-available">
  <div class="mplc-widget-header">Available options</div>
  <div class="mplc-widget-middle"><input></input></div>
  <div class="mplc-widget-choices">
   <table>
    {{each(i, choice) choices}}
     <tr name="${choice[0]}">
      <td>${choice[1]}</td>
     </tr>
    {{/each}}
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="mplc-widget-selector">
  <div><button>A</button></div>
  <div><button>B</button></div>
 </div>
 <div class="mplc-widget-chosen">
  <div class="mplc-widget-header">Selected options</div>
  <div class="mplc-widget-choices">
   <table>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

after rendering this template (with `widget = $.tmpl(...)`) button A and button B are bound to a `click` event, like this:

```
$('button', widget).bind('click', function(){alert('Hello world!');})
```

Then `widget` is returned. The functions which renders the previous template and binds the events, is being called in another template:

```
<!-- TEMPLATE B -->
<div class='form'>
 <table>
  {{each(i, field) fields}}
   <tr>
    {{if field.fieldname}}
     <p>
      <td {{if field.required}} class='field-required'{{/if}}>
       ${field.label}:</td> <td>{{tmpl field.create()}}
       {{if field.help_text}}<br/><span class='help_text'>${field.help_text}</span>{{/if}}
      </td>
     </p>
    </tr>
   {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
 </table>
</div>
```

In this template `{{tmpl field.create()}}` represents the function which renders and returns `template A`. All the element are displayed fine when inserted into the DOM, but the bind function (set in `create`) are lost!

Is this the correct behaviour or am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm still not able to apply the logic explained above. However: I was able to apply a workaround, using [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery). It is not ideal, but it works.